# tkinter загрузить картинку

Tags: python

хочу загрузить картинку на готовый интерфейс, но не получается. помогите!! пишет что 
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

```
import smtplib # Библиотека для отправки сообщений на mail
from email.mime.text import MIMEText # Модуль smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import pygame
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import *

import os
screen = Tk()

screen.geometry('900x900')
screen.title("WELCOME TO THE GAME!")

lbl = Label(screen, text="...",font=("Arial Bold", 18),fg='#0F0')
lbl.grid(column=1, row=1)
screen["bg"] = "gray22"
lbl["bg"] = "gray22"
###
app_root = Tk()

#Setting it up
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("1.png"))

#Displaying it
imglabel = Label(app_root, image=img).grid(row=1, column=1)        


app_root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить строку `img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("1.png"))`
на `img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="1.png")`